# Get value from JSON when 2 condition are true

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps in my application and I'm adding markers to my map by getting the latitude and longitude from JSON, my JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Hotel 1"
    "lat": "39.323523",
    "long": "-3.036840"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hotel 2"
    "lat": "39.323523",
    "long": "-2.937963"
  }
]
```

This works fine, the markers are set like it should be. Now, when I tap on a marker I get the latitude and longitude but doing the following:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            //Getting the lat and long based on marker position clicked
            Double latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            Double longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

            return false;
        }
    });
```

This also works fine, I get the correct latitude and longitude whenever I tap on a marker.

---

This is where my question starts; What I want to do now is get the name from my JSON file if 2 values are true. In my `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener` I call this:

`getInfoJson("39.323523", "-3.036840");`

So, if the latitude is `39.323523` and the longitude is `-3.036840` then I want to get the name.

Here is my method:

```
private void getInfoJson(final String lati, final String longi) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {                        
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            //Getting lat and long from JSONObject
                            mLat = o.getString("lat");
                            mLong = o.getString("long");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Has anybody dealt with this issue and can someone please clarify how this is possible?

Comment: use `.equals` method of `String` class.

Comment: just confirming, the GET request gets your JSON array which you want to parse to see if the latitudes and longitudes match ? and if they do you want to return the name ?

Comment: @casualcoder Sorry I missed your comment, yes that is exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try :**

```
private void getInfoJson(final String lati, final String longi) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {                        
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            //Getting lat and long from JSONObject
                            mLat = o.getString("lat");
                            mLong = o.getString("long");
                            if(lati.equals(mLat) && longi.equals(mLong)) 
                            {
                               //get name here
                               name = o.getString("name");
                            }else {

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

************** EDIT *****************

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener listener = (GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) marker.getTag();

            //Getting the lat and long based on marker position clicked
            Double latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            Double longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

            getInfoJson(latitude, longitude);

            return listener != null && listener.onMarkerClick(marker);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried this and it returns the name no matter what marker is tapped, I only want to return the name when selecting the marker with corresponding lat and long.

Comment: Now it only returns when one marker is tapped, I think the issue could be because the for loop should be broken `break;`??

Comment: @ClassA also try putting logs in on click listner to see if every time getting lat long

Comment: @ClassA In this answer i have checked the map lat long with the json lat long if both matches then get the name and in else i haven't done anything. So in this case the name will returned only when both lat long matches. this is what you need right?

Comment: I tried adding a `break` in the if statement and I called a `Log`. Only hotel 2 gets returned, in the log it displays all the lat and long when calling `Log.i("LOG", mLat+"-"+mLong);`

Comment: @ClassA yes this is correct because only hotel 2 lat long match with marker.. see your json hotel 1 and hotel 2 long is different. do you need that if only lat or only long match then return name?? then can use `||` instead `&&`

Comment: @ClassA no need of break statement

Comment: Let me update my question with what I tried and the outcome

Comment: @ClassA just try `||` once in if instead `&&` may be it will solve your problem

Comment: It then returns both names no matter what marker is selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170060/discussion-between-vishva-dave-and-classa).